Spectogram: Short-time Fourier Transform vs Time-Frequency Wavelet Transform
So far, I used STFT a.k.a windowed fourier transform for convert signal to time-frequency domain.
In general, the parameter I can tune is window size, where smaller window size lead lower frequency resolution but higher time resolution. And vice versa. The resulted spectogram is consistent.
I have read that the Wavelet Transform can be used to create spectogram, the different result is, the resolution between frequency and time is not linear. In another word, lower frequency has higher time resolution while higher frequency has low time resolution. What is the intuition behind this?
My goal is, I want convert any arbitrary signal to the spectogram.
Suppose I have signal with length 1000 samples, I chose to limit the frequency range output within range a to b. I want the spectogram result has balanced information between frequency information and time information.
So, what is the different between STFT and Time-Freq WT?

Well, the obvious difference is that the Wavelet Transform splits the signal up into frequency bands first, before applying any windowing.  The bandwidth of each frequency band is proportional to the frequencies of that band (i.e. higher frequency bands have wider bandwidth).  And then the big thing is that higher frequency bands (that are wider bandwidth) have narrower windows applied and shorter hop lengths (and more windowed segments per unit time) applied between adjacent windows.

Does this answer https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/comparison-between-fourier-transform-short-time-fourier-transform-and-wavelets or these answers https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/wavelet-transform-and-stft help at all?
